# Executing .exec file using Objective-C Code on my mac

Tags: python, objective-c, exec

I am trying to make some edits on RWTS-PDFWriter Source Code:
https://github.com/3gx/RWTS-PDFwriter
To make it execute an exec file when it saves the pdf to make some changes on it. but when I hit print it always shows me that there is a backend error.
I am not very good at Objective-C, I need this project for my university assignment.

I added the code block to the pdfwriter.m file.

`@autoreleasepool {`

`[[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"/private/var/spool/spaceprinter/QrMake.py"`

`arguments:@[@"/Users/philipnakhleh/Desktop/pos.pdf"]]`

`waitUntilExit];`

`}`

but it shows me a backend error when I print. But, when I run the same code on a separate project it runs without problems.

Any Help??

Comment: Why duplicate the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75275701/executing-exec-file-using-objective-c-code ? What's the error you get? What back-end?

Comment: there is no error displayed, but the command to run a program is not working.
I wrote a script to make a directory, it worked well.

Comment: "I hit print it always shows me that there is a backend error." Isn't that an error? What's the full error then?

Comment: You don't read `standardInput`, `standardError`? Is that code inside an sandboxed app? Do you have enough rights?

Comment: No, I don't read any input so I don't use standard input and there is no standard Error Reading also.
I don't know if it is a sandboxed or not I don't know well about the macOS system.
I gave everyone permission to execute the .exec file

Comment: Again, " it shows me a backend error when I print": What error? What do you print? It's hard to tell what's wrong without more info. We can't guess what's failing, is it "your code" part, is it the python script? Maybe the script output errors infos messages on why it failed in `standardInput` and `standartError` , so, try to check them, because currently, if it's actually sending an error, you are ignoring it, and we aren't magicians, we can't guess it.